# Python array for a begginner

Tags: python, arrays, input

I just started Python and have some questions about arrays. I don't understand them at all. I was given a project and was wondering if someone could help. I have to make a 1x4 box. The user gets to pick one of the four boxes where an A will then appear. The other three boxes then fill up with B C D.

```
somearray = []
    index= input("")-1
    char = raw_input("")
    somearray[] = char
```

This is what i was given to work with. I also know that an input or `raw_input` will be needed.

```
def drawArray():
    somearray = []
    index = input("1 , 2 , 3 , 4") - 1
    char = raw_input("A , B , C, D ")
    somearray[] = char
```

This is what I have put in. I am not sure where I should go from here. If someone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague as to what you need us to help you with (the exact desired result--with the user picking a box--is unclear as well). Does the user input a string ("A", "B", "C", or "D"), or does s/he click on a box?

Comment: it's [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on python

Comment: the [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) docs page for comparison

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean something like this ?

```
>>> def func():
    ind=input("enter the index :")-1
    lis=['B','C','D']
    lis.insert(ind,'A')
    return lis
   ....: 

>>> func()
enter the index :1
>>> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

>>> func()
enter the index :2
>>> ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D']

>>> func()
enter the index :3
>>> ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']
```

Comment: Ya this is great thanks for the help. Sorry for being vague. It was when a user chose a number from 1~4 (corresponding with a box) The letter 'A' would appear in the box that was picked. After the A was picked then the rest were filled with B C and D. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @Budderz I think that's what this program is doing.